# how to use sql view in android room library

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I'm going to create SQL view in android. I know for this purpose I should use this syntax in my DAO file:

```
    @DatabaseView("Select Name, Address From Customer")
    data class UserInfoView(
        val name: String,
        val address: String
    )
```

and change my database class like this:

```
@Database(
    entities = [CustomerTable::class],
    views = [CustomerDAO.UserInfoView::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
```

but I have no idea how to use this view!
in SQL the views work just like tables but how can I use this view in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Database `View` just as you use an `Entity` in `DAO`.

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM UserInfoView")
    fun getUserInfo(): List<UserInfoView>
}
```

You can not do `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` operations with Database View. I couldn't find an example in `Android` documentation for accessing the `View`. So, please check this [example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10194335-database-views-with-room-for-android) for getting more info on this.